# Updated Realm Objects with no actual change are counted in the RealmCollectionChange

Tags: ios, swift, realm

If a `Realm` `Object` is included in a `Realm.add(_:update:)` with `update` set to `true`, its index is included in the resultant `RealmCollectionChange`, even when none of its properties changed.

In my case, I'm parsing JSON, which is then turned into my specific `Object`.  Some of these will have been changed, some not, and some will be entirely new.  So when I `realm.add(possiblyNewOrUpdatedObjects, update: true)`, Objects whose values didn't change at all are included in the `modifications` index array.

Is there something I'm missing about this behavior? Why are non-modified `Object`s considered modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, that's the accepted functionality. If you set a property on an `Object`, even if it's the same value as before, that still counts as a change modification.

There's [an issue on the Realm Cocoa repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3489) discussing this functionality and if it should be considered a bug that needs fixing. Issue priorities at Realm are determined by how many users ask about it, so please add your support to that issue. :)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've added my  to the relevant comments.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Realm.add(_:update:)`, `Realm` tries to verify that the object is managed and make sure that the object you are adding is managing by the same `Realm`. Then it will try to get or create row (fetch or create an object) before populate all properties.

Basically `Realm` doesn't know what are the value of each properties you are trying to update. `Realm` only sees them as a new object.

Comment: But no, it does show up as an "updated" Object, instead of an "inserted" Object.  The problem is just that it shouldn't be included in "updated" either.